# How do I make this accordion script 100% width?

Tags: jquery

How do I make this accordion script 100% width? I need the width to adapt to browser.

Here's the  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N3Sh7/12)

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    width:651,
    height:400,
    barSize:40,
    cover:true,
    coverAlpha:1,
    shadow:false,
    shadowAlpha:1,
    border:true,
    borderSize:1,
    borderColor:"#242424",
    transitionTime:0.3,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTime:5,
    changeType:"click"
});
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the first line *width:651,* of the javascript code?

Comment: Tried deleting it, tried specifying % and tampered with the css with no effect.

Comment: Inspect in chrome's Elements tab

Comment: I would be very grateful if anyone can help me figure this out. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34896665/5678086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it http://jsfiddle.net/N3Sh7/19/

You have to give it like below with quotes

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
width:"100%",
height:400,
barSize:40,
cover:true,
coverAlpha:1,
shadow:false,
shadowAlpha:1,
border:true,
borderSize:1,
borderColor:"#242424",
transitionTime:0.3,
autoplay:true,
autoplayTime:5,
changeType:"click"
});
```